# apache2 SVN (authz) setup. Want second website to only allow those with rw permissions

Tags: apache, svn, apache2, authz

I have an apache2.4 setup hosting subversion (SVN) repositories wonderfully.  I use an authz file to control access to my repositories, and give different users different permissions to different repositories.

I am now making a companion site, (It's in python cgi) and would like to use the same user file to restrict or allow access, but only allow access to the second site when the user has r/w (not just r) permissions for the primary svn site.

Is this possible in apache2 & authz, or do I need to set up this semi-advanced authentication in my python module(s)?

Comment: Your statement is not very clear. How is a cgi script (python or otherwise) even involved with the apache2 authz module? Doesn't apache intercept the request before it even reaches your cgi script?

Comment: Yes.  I would like apache to enforce allowing users with r/w permissions itself.  I brought the python up because if this is not possible, I could with some effort implement this authentication myself in the python. (Via os.environ["REMOTE_USER"])